# Stop private class variables from showing in PHP

Tags: php

I may be misunderstanding the point of Visibility in PHP.

The following code:

```
<?php

class Test {
    private $_secret;
    
    public function __construct() {
        $this->_secret = 'Why are you seeing this?';
    }
}

$me = new Test();
print_r($me);
```

Reveals the private variable:

```
Test Object
(
    [_secret:Test:private] => Why are you seeing this?
)
```

[Link to code](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f0ba525da3133fca9c997ccde36f2e56aa993ac9)

**Can I stop this from happening** or is this meant to happen?

Comment: This is a dump to debug like `var_dump()`. Of course this is intended. You won't get them when implementing using `__toString()`.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php#refsect1-function.print-r-description

**print_r()**, **var_dump()** and **var_export()** will also show protected and private properties of objects. Static class members will not be shown.

**print_r** shows private properties for debugging purposes. If you want to display information about an object, you can create a method, for example - **toString**  to return the appropriate information.